# Detect user idle (per application instance)

Tags: c#, .net, idle-processing

I need user idle detection in my application only (per "my application instance").
I can't use *[GetLastInputInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646302%28VS.85%29.aspx)* because is **session-specific user input**:

> GetLastInputInfo **does not** provide system-wide user input information across all running sessions. Rather, GetLastInputInfo provides **session-specific user input** information for only the session that invoked the function.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: what kind of application is that? Windows Application? you have it running on multiple computers? what do you want to get?

Comment: Yes, **Windows Application**. It can be running on the same machine on the same "Windows User"

Comment: When you say "per application instance", do you mean checking for idle on all running applications in the system, or just your own application?

Comment: Just **my own application** only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`Application.AddMessageFilter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.addmessagefilter.aspx) and watch for messages representing user interaction (e.g. mouse, keyboard, maybe menu activation).

Answer (score 5):

I assume you want to detect the idle time but only when you application is active. You then have to define exactly what you mean by your application being active. When your application is active (by your own definition) you can at regular intervals call [GetLastInputInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646302%28VS.85%29.aspx) to determine the idle time of your application when it is active (e.g. using a timer of some sort).

Windows has a concept of a foreground window and the current foreground window can be retrived using [GetForegroundWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You can use [GetWindowThreadProcessId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633522%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to find the process ID of the process owning the foreground window. If that process ID is your process ID you know that you are the foreground process even if your application has multiple windows. You will have to do this detection at regular intervals just as you have to check the idle time.

You should not be concerned about `GetLastInputInfo` only providing information about the session. If multiple users are logged onto the same Windows computer they will each have their own session, but another user being idle or not ilde in a session should not affect how you detect if the user of your application is idle.

Comment: I want to detect the idle time when my application is active and inactive. I mean when is minimlized, when maxmalized but user works with oter application, when user works with my application (active) but doing nothing (not using mouse, keyboard, etc.)

Comment: When my application is active (by my own definition, above) I can't use _GetLastInputInfo_ at regular intervals, for example when my app is minimlized (in my own definition, my app is active).

Answer (score 2):

If this is a Windows Forms application, you can create an idle event handler and subscribe to the [Application.Idle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.idle.aspx) event.  You'll get a notification when the application finishes processing and is about to enter the idle state.

Comment: I need notification on user idle, not application idle. My application has a lot of background processing taks.

Comment: @halorty: As far as `Application.Idle` is concerned, "idle" is user interface idle.  When the UI thread is done processing and about to enter the idle state, you get the `Application.Idle` event.  Stuff happening on background threads isn't going to change that.